# Como reorganizar de forma aleatória uma lista de Strings e selecionar um elemento por vez sem que se repita o valor contido na lista?

Tags: java, android, firebase, lista

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em Android studio em linguagem Java e preciso saber como resolver meu problema.

Eu tenho uma lista de `String`:

```
List<String> valores = new ArrayList<>();
```

Dai então eu crio um loop `for` para adicionar `Strings` a essa Lista.
Exemplo:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    valores.add(disp[i]);
}
```

Continuando o raciocínio, digamos que ao final desse loop `for` a minha lista ficou assim e nessa ordem:

> "Pera" (na posição 0),
>   "Maça" (na posição 1) ,
>   "Uva" (na posição 2),
>   "Banana" (na posição 3) e
>   "Abacaxi" (na posição 4)

O que eu preciso é reorganizar de forma aleatória as posições dos itens da minha Lista e criar um método que pegue cada item de uma vez sem que o mesmo valor se repita.

Por exemplo: eu reorganizei as posições e a minha Lista ficou dessa forma:

> "Uva" (na posição 0),
>   "Banana" (na posição 1),
>   "Abacaxi" (na posição 2),
>   "Maça" (na posição 3) e
>   "Pera" (na posição 4)

Agora, como exemplo, imagine que eu tenho um botão e que quando eu clico nesse botão, ele me mostre a primeira posição que é no caso "Uva" e  que quando eu clico no botão de novo ele me mostre a segunda opção que é banana.

A minha real intenção era usar `Collections.shuffle(valores)`
para embaralhar a lista e depois usar algum método que indique quais itens da minha lista já foram mostrados.

Isso tudo porque eu quero usar o realtime database do firebase para fazer a seguinte situação:

Eu tenho 3 usuários conectados. Daí então eu mando uma mensagem para o primeiro usuário com uma pergunta. Se o primeiro usuário responder "sim" o loop vai se interromper e meu aplicativo indicará para mim que ele aceitou e se ele disser não, então esse usuário é descartado e a mensagem é enviada ao segundo e assim por diante. Até que alguém responda sim ou então que todos digam não.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, para embaralhar a lista você pode criar uma extensão para `List<>` como:

```
private static Random rng = new Random();  

public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
// USAR
List<Product> products = GetProducts();
products.Shuffle();
```

Para saber quais itens você já mostrou crie outra lista e adicione os elementos a ela quando você clicar no botão, depois você pode verificar se esse elemento já foi mostrado com método `visualizados.conteins(KEY)`.

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo.... vou fazer dessa forma!